# Structuring an ASP.NET MVC (Entity Framework) app

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some general questions about the MVC pattern and structuring my application.  In my application, I have multiple unrelated entities that I will be managing.  In most instances an entity can be more than 1 database table.

For example, an application might manage Persons and Fruit.  There is no relationship between Persons and Fruit.

The Persons entity is made up of multiple tables.

```
**Person**
PersonID
JobID
LocationID

**Job**
JobID
Name

**Location**
LocationID
Name
```

The Fruit entity (totally unrelated to Person) is also made up of multiple tables.

```
**Fruit**
FruitID
ColorID
ShapeID

**Color**
ColorID
name

**Shape**
ShapeID
Name
```

So within my project I have a model class for each database table.  I have a controller for each entity (FruitController and PersonController)

So here is where my confusion arises:

Should I have a DBContext for each entity or 1 DBContext for the entire project?

Now let's say I create a migration for this project.  Creating a migration, gives me a configuration.cs file in my Migrations folder.  Open up that file and there is a Seed method which takes a DBContext as a paramater.  If your answer to the previous question was to have a DBContext for each entity, then how can I seed each entity since I'm passing the DBContext in as a parameter?

Next comes the repository.
Should I have a repository for each entity or 1 for each table?

I already know there are tons of examples out there showing how to set these things up, but most of them just show the basic pieces of how to do things. I think I'm shooting for something the next level up from the basic examples.

Comment: You can create new tags. Just so you know

Comment: Didn't know.  I did find it hard to believe that I was the first one asking an MVC5 question, so it made me think that someone else was creating the tags.

Comment: People can be Fruits, you know! :) The rule of thumb I've always applied is to have 1 context for each database you're connecting to. If the Person and Fruit objects are stored in the same DB, it's the same context.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the same DBContext file for both entities, it's more difficult keeping the database up to date with your model if you use 2. This also solves the problem of the multiple seed files.

Then you should create a different repository for each entity (so 1 for Fruits and 1 for Persons). They would both get the same DBContext injected in their constructor.

Of course this isn't set in stone, you should use the method which makes most sense for you.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it more, if you are using the build in security, you already have an ApplicationContext, so I may wind up having more than 1 context